# Taking user input in a switch statement in java

Tags: java, switch-statement, user-input

I need help making this switch statement, taking a user input in order to pick (in this case) the month that will be printed. Instead of just always printing august, how would I take a user input and let them choose the month?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class SwitchDemo {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int UsrIn;


            UsrIn = input.nextInt();

            int month = UsrIn;

            String monthString;
            switch (month) {
                case 1:  monthString = "January";
                         break;
                case 2:  monthString = "February";
                         break;
                case 3:  monthString = "March";
                         break;
                case 4:  monthString = "April";
                         break;
                case 5:  monthString = "May";
                         break;
                case 6:  monthString = "June";
                         break;
                case 7:  monthString = "July";
                         break;
                case 8:  monthString = "August";
                         break;
                case 9:  monthString = "September";
                         break;
                case 10: monthString = "October";
                         break;
                case 11: monthString = "November";
                         break;
                case 12: monthString = "December";
                         break;
                default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                         break;
            }
            System.out.println(monthString);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you do some research instead of copy/paste the code in [the switch statement page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)?

Comment: @ZouZou to be fair, him finding that page shows he did some research...

Comment: @ZouZou Yeah, I tried putting it in Java, adding a scanner, and trying to take it from the user but I guess I didn't format it right.

Comment: But the `switch` is completely irrelevant, since the question is "How do I get an integer as input from the user?" Show the code you're having a problem with, not the code you found in the Java documentation.

Comment: @TheThom He showed me the page.

Comment: @Wooble So you wouldn't use the two together? I'm sorry, I'm really confused on when I need to use it them.

Comment: @TheThom I showed him the page in his previous question (which was deleted)...

Comment: @ZouZou I stand corrected.

Comment: "I tried putting it in Java, adding a scanner, and trying to take it from the user" --> show us **this**, then maybe you can get help with your actual problem.

Comment: @Wooble He answered the question but thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
int month = 8;
```

with

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please entter month: ");
String msg = in.nextLine();
int month = Integer.valueOf(msg);
```

Comment: @Eqorip Use `int month = in.nextInt();` instead. No need to take a String as input and parse it to int after.